# More concise word or phrase for "people who have been taken advantage of"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I’m hoping for a single descriptive word for “people who have been taken advantage of”, but a shorter phrase would be ok.

These are people who now have a lack of trust and are in need of loyalty in their relationships.

Comment: _Victim_ is the usual term; modified if necessary by a noun or adjective -- _murder victim, shooting victim, fraud victim,_ etc.

Comment: @Sam Washburn Are you looking for a noun or an adjective?

Comment: @Elian A noun would be best.

Comment: Those people are called **people**.  The 99%.  Huddled masses yearning to breathe free... ;-)

Comment: What do you need this word for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A more decisive answer to your query might be *exploited*.  For example:

> Mr. X had very little knowledge about market prices and as such he was heavily **exploited** by the retailers.

Comment: These are all great answers, but exploited seemed like the best fit to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

One of these might work:

- [dupe](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dupe?s=t)

> dupe1   [doop, dyoop]
> noun
>
> `1`. a person who is easily deceived or fooled; gull.
>
> `2`. a person who unquestioningly or unwittingly serves a cause or another person: a dupe of the opponents.
>
> verb (used with object), duped, dup·ing.
>
> `3`. to make a dupe of; deceive; delude; trick.

- [victim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/victim?s=t)

> `2`. a person who is deceived or cheated, as by his or her own emotions or ignorance, by the dishonesty of others, or by some impersonal agency: a victim of misplaced confidence; the victim of a swindler; a victim of an optical illusion.

Answer (score 8):

It is a harsh term but I think the word I hear the most is *sucker*.

> Usage:
>
> John gave his teenage daughter more money for clothes, he is such a
>   sucker.
>
> I am such a sucker, why would I ever believe that men want anything
>   but sex.

Comment: [For the use–mention distinction, please use an *italic* face not a **bold** one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364)

Comment: @tchrist - sorry but shouldn't you lead by example in your comments?

Comment: I did so, by showing the difference between the two effects.

Comment: @tchrist - but should the entire sentence be a link?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Perhaps not.

Comment: Sure, this is the obviosu answer.  "There's a sucker born every minute" is a common phrase and song, Sam.

Comment: I'm not sure this term fits the example use he gave. They may be a sucker while they're being conned, but once they go through it and lose trust, they're probably not a sucker any more.

Comment: @Barmar - I have been suckered many times in my life.  Regarding the situations I will always remain a sucker.  Not sure you can lose that state (of what you were).

Comment: I've been suckered. I would say that I _was_ a sucker when I got taken in by that penny stock scam, but now I'm more wary and I (hopefully) won't be a sucker again.

Comment: @Barmar - but you still consider yourself a sucker in that instance.  I am not saying it is permanent.  I am saying it is permanent for that state (your penny stock adventure.)

Comment: But the question is how to refer to the victims _afterward_, when they've learned their lesson. Now they're distrustful, not suckers any more.

Answer (score 7):

A word usually carries certain implications with it. Your question seems to be searching for two distinct meanings.

1. A word or phrase to identify "people who have been taken advantage of…" might be "dupe", "patsy", "stooge", "sucker", "fool", "fallen angel", "mark", "victim", etc.
2. Someone who, by being duped in the past, is distrustful of others' intents might be a "cynic", a "hard-boiled egg", "doubting Thomas", "skeptic", "churl", "pessimist", "curmudgeon" etc.

And perhaps another for someone who needs loyalty in their relationships.

The word to be used depends on which meaning you want your audience to infer the most.

Answer (score 4):

*Hurt* or *damaged* could be used in a relationship sense.

I’m sure *damaging relationship* is a fairly common term these days.

Answer (score 4):

What comes to mind are such phrases as *once bitten/burned, twice shy* and *a burnt child dreads the fire*.

> [*once bitten/burned, twice shy*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Once+bitten,+twice+shy) and [*a burnt child dreads the fire*](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=fgaUQc8NbTYC&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=%22burnt+child+dreads%22+swindled&source=bl&ots=eUxZbhpsQ4&sig=o8yX_6CIQCxzOZYUN-Ah6DxVmhI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=_7p3U4CsHc2Y0QXW_oHABg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22burnt%20child%20dreads%22%20swindled&f=false): something that you say which means that when you had an unpleasant experience you are much more careful to avoid such similar experiences in the future.

Alternately, consider *victimized,* *used*, *put-upon,* and *suckered*.

> [*victimized; used; put-upon; (slang) suckered*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/victimized): *(of persons)* taken advantage of.

In the way of nouns, consider *patsy* and *fall guy*.

> [*patsy*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patsy): a person who is easily swindled, deceived, coerced, persuaded, etc.; sucker.
>
> [*fall guy*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fall+guy): an easy victim.

Comment: [For the use–mention distinction, please use an *italic* face not a **bold** one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is good. But IMO "victimized" is as good, or perhaps an even better choice, because you added:

> people who now have a lack of trust and are in need of loyalty in
>   their relationships.

"Exploited" means some has been taken advantage of - "used" - but they are not necessarily aware of the fact, or see anything particularly wrong with it. On the contrary, "exploited" is usually used when the victims don't know they've been used and don't realize any wrong has been done. "Victimized" however, means exactly that - someone who has been made to suffer - been made into a **victim**.

Answer (score 2):

*[Gudgeon](http://english_contemporary.enacademic.com/83612/gudgeon)*: gudg·eon || 'gʌdʒən n. type of freshwater fish; **gullible person**, one who can be cheated easily; bait, lure

*[Gobemouche](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/215695/gobemouche)*: n. (pl. gobemouches pronunc. same) a **gullible listener**.

Comment: These are very unusual terms to use.

Comment: The question is "a single descriptive word for "people who have been taken advantage of'", and I cannot edit my answer according to a person's familiarity (nor, the fact that there is likely no other answer).  Perhaps I am mistaken in that the mission of this site is to understand the English language,  and the goal is truly to 'play idem per idem' game?

Comment: Your posting is hopelessly [mojibaked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), probably because of Microsoft’s incompetence at character encodings, not your own. Still, please fix.

Comment: The goal is to make the English language accessible.  That means preferring words that people actually use. Even if the goal were to introduce arcane words for the heck of it, though, these two wouldn't quite fit; "have been taken advantage of" and "can be taken advantage of" are two different things, particularly given the people the OP is trying to describe (who lack trust, making them more wary and less gullible).

Comment: Good god...“people who have been taken advantage of” are 
gudgeoned and  gobemouched. "English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about English language and usage." I do not find my reply to be contradictory to the stated mission

Comment: **Gudgeon** does not even appear in any dictionary.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany,  English contemporary dictionary. 2014., The Collaborative International Dictionary of English, Etymology dictionary,...

Comment: ***Please* correct your mojibake!** If that is meant to be a pronunciation, then be apprised that the OED has **ˈgʌdʒən** for *gudgeon* and unstressed (because it is unassimilated French, which lacks phonemic stress) **gɔbəmuʃ** for *gobemouche*.  Note also that those are actually meant to be /broad phonemics/ not [narrow phonetics].

Answer (score 2):

You could also go with "sucker" if you want to use a casual tone and to convey that they were exploited because of their own excessive credulity.

Answer (score 1):

I think *profit* with the meaning “to derive advantage, to benefit from” can be used in that sense.

- to profit from the weaknesses of others
- He is a *profiteer*.

Answer (score 1):

You might call them the *damaged party*.

Answer (score 1):

A "tool" informally refers to someone who has been used without knowing it.

Comment: Your answer would be well-served with examples and, if possible, a citation.

Comment: I'm not so sure "tool" means "without knowing it" - I generally understand it to mean someone who's a "stooge", but they often know exactly what their position is, and they are consciously acting as a "tool", which is often quite a lucrative job... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As well as the terms *sucker* and *mark* already mentioned, a similar expression (which also denotes something like 'victim' or 'potential victim' among confidence tricksters, professional gamblers, etc.) is *rube*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the choice of word will depend on how you want the reader to view the victims. Words like "dupe", "patsy" and "sucker" imply that the person was foolish. I hear 'sucker' used as an insult or taunt. Such words might be used by the perpetrators of a fraud to devalues their victims (the "marks") in their own eyes.

A word like victim or exploited is more neutral. They are not in some way to blame for their misfortune. The blame rests with the perpetrators.